# Is TPM NV deletion protection possible?

Tags: tpm

I want to implement a counter that cannot be tampered with using TPM.

It seems that it is possible to force data not to be written by enabling only nv-increment.

However, if nv is deleted with nv-undefine and then recreated, the counter is reset.

Is there a best way to achieve this goal even if being security not perfect?

---

Or can I designate an administrator for the TPM?
The administrator's private key is required to modify data, but is nv-increment possible without a key?